# Angular/Ionic - How to group data from two JSON source?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, grouping

I want to group data JSON into accordion list in Ionic. How can I do that with two JSON source?

Previously I did successfully with only one JSON.

I have two JSON that look like this.
The one :

```
    {
        {
          "ObjectId": '001',
          "ObjectName": 'Fruits'
        },
        {
          "ObjectId": '002',
          "ObjectName": 'Vegetables'
        }
    }
```

The other one :

```
    {
        {
          "Name": 'Apple',
          "Color": 'Red',
          "ObjectId": '001'
        },
        {
          "Name": 'Eggplant',
          "Color": 'Purple',
          "ObjectId": '002'
        },
        {
          "Name": 'Banana',
          "Color": 'Yellow',
          "ObjectId": '001'
        },
        {
          "Name": 'Spinach',
          "Color": 'Green',
          "ObjectId": '002'
        },
        {
          "Name": 'Garlic',
          "Color": 'White',
          "ObjectId": '002'
        },
    }
```

Here my expected result image :
[Accordion-List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7AXS.png)

Comment: Share your code and ask where you are stuck?

Comment: Thaks for the respond. I've found the solution, but i'm not sure my method is the best way. I'll show the method in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, but i'm not sure my method is the best way.

Here is my method :

```
// GET DATA API
let getObjectApi = this.dataProvider.getObjectUrl();
new Promise(resolve => {
    getObjectApi.subscribe(data => {
      resolve(data);
      this.apiObjectData = data;

      // LOOPING OBJECT DATA
      for (let i = 0; i < this.apiObjectData.length; i++) {
        const objItem = data[i];

        // GET OBJECT ITEM BY ObjectId
        let getObjectItem = this.getObjectItemByObjectId('ObjectId', objItem['ObjectId']);
        // PUSH THE DATA
        this.apiDataResult.push({
          'dataObject': objItem,
          'dataObjectItem' : getObjectItem 
        });
      }
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
```

And here `this.getObjectItemByObjectId()` method :

```
getObjectItemByObjectId(column, value) {
  let result:any = [];
  let dataApi: any = [];

  let getObjectItemApi = this.dataProvider.getObjectItemUrl();
  new Promise(resolve => {
    getObjectItemApi.subscribe(data => {
      resolve(data);
      dataApi = data;
      for (let i = 0; i < dataApi.length; i++) {
        const element = dataApi[i];
        if (element[column] == value) {
          result.push(element);
        }
      }
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });

  return result;
}
```

And the result is something like this :

```
{
    {
      "dataObject": {
                      "ObjectId": '001',
                      "ObjectName": 'Fruits'
                    },
      "dataObjectItem": {
                            {
                              "Name": 'Apple',
                              "Color": 'Red',
                              "ObjectId": '001'
                            },
                            {
                              "Name": 'Banana',
                              "Color": 'Yellow',
                              "ObjectId": '001'
                            }
                        }
    },
    {
      "dataObject": {
                      "ObjectId": '002',
                      "ObjectName": 'Vegetables'
                    },
      "dataObjectItem": {
                            {
                              "Name": 'Eggplant',
                              "Color": 'Purple',
                              "ObjectId": '002'
                            },
                            {
                              "Name": 'Spinach',
                              "Color": 'Green',
                              "ObjectId": '002'
                            },
                            {
                              "Name": 'Garlic',
                              "Color": 'White',
                              "ObjectId": '002'
                            }
                        }
    }
}
```

That's all!

> If there is a better way than my method, please let me know! And sorry if something is goes wrong. Thank you in advance !!